# Modificar Tabla con un boton? en html asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

ahora me encuentro haciendo una tabla con boostrap (y un par de etiquetas de asp) pero me surge un problema.

Estoy intentando que con un botón que esta en la tabla se despliegue un modal que permita modificar esos valores.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen por cada registro en la tabla se agrega un boton, el cual despliega el modal para editar los datos.

parte de mis preguntas son:

1. como puedo enviar los datos, por ejemplo, del primer registro a una serie de text box, Check Box... que estarían ubicados en el Modal.
2. Es mejor replantear el ejercicio?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour], leas [ask] y agregues un [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Saludos

Comment: Como enviar los datos de la fila a dónde??? al modal , al servidor???.- Favor coloca algo de código para entender el contexto